# Wordpress: Learnpress courses order/orderby

Tags: php, wordpress, learnpress

I need to change order at "all courses" page. Default it's by date, i need to make it lower to higer price. Which hook i need to use? I tried few but im total newbie and nothing works. Thanks for help and ur time.

Comment: Have you tried contacting this plugin's support? This sounds like a question for them. If you want help from SO, please try to post a [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.